# Three factor plotting using xyplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I had a problem with ggplot that I am not able to solve, so maybe someone here can point out the reason. Sorry that I am not able to upload my dataset, but some data description can be found below. The output of the ggplot is shown below, except NO line, every other thing is OK.

```
> all.data<-read.table("D:/PAM/data/Rural_Recovery_Edit.csv",head=T,sep=",")
> all.data$Water<-factor(all.data$Water,labels=c("W30","W60","W90"))
> all.data$Polymer<-factor(all.data$Polymer,labels=c("PAM-0  ","PAM-10  ","PAM-40  "))
> all.data$Group<-factor(all.data$Group,labels=c("Day20","Day25","Day30"))
> dat<-data.frame(Waterconsump=all.data[,9],Water=all.data$Water,Polymer=all.data$Polymer,Age=all.data$Group)

> ggplot(dat,aes(x=Water,y=Waterconsump,colour=Polymer))+
+ stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="line",size=2)+
+ stat_summary(fun.ymin=min,fun.ymax=max,geom="errorbar")+#,position="dodge"
+ facet_grid(~Age)

> dim(dat)
[1] 108   4
> head(dat)
  Waterconsump Water  Polymer   Age
1         10.5   W30 PAM-10   Day20
2         10.3   W30 PAM-10   Day20
3         10.1   W30 PAM-10   Day20
4          7.7   W30 PAM-10   Day20
5          8.6   W60 PAM-10   Day20
6          8.4   W60 PAM-10   Day20
> table(dat$Water)

W30 W60 W90 
 36  36  36 
> table(dat$Polymer)

 PAM-0   PAM-10   PAM-40   
      36       36       36 
> table(dat$Age)

Day20 Day25 Day30 
   36    36    36
```

[image: The out put of the ggplot]
and, if I changed the geom into "bar", the output is OK.
[image: The ggplot output when geom="bar"]

```
below is the background for this Q
```

#

I would like to plot several variables that were subjected to the same, 3 factors. Using xyplot, I am able to plot 2 of them, within one figure. However, I have no idea how to include the third, and arrange the figure into N subplots (N equals the level number of the third factor). 
So, my aims would be:

1. Plot the 3rd facotors, and split the plot into N subplots, where N is the levels of the 3rd factor.
2. Better to work as a function, as I need to plot a several variables.
   Below is the example figure with only two factors, and my working example to plot 2 factors.

Thanks in advance~

Marco

```
library(reshape)
library(agricolae)
library(lattice)
yr<-gl(10,3,90:99)
trt<-gl(4,75,labels=c("A","B","C","D"))

third<-gl(3,100,lables=c("T","P","Q")) ### The third factor to split the figure in to 4 subplots

dat<-cbind(runif(300),runif(300,min=1,max=10),runif(300,min=100,max=200),runif(300,min=1000,max=1500))
colnames(dat)<-paste("Item",1:4,sep="-")
fac<-factor(paste(trt,yr,sep="-"))
dataov<-aov(dat[,1]~fac)
dathsd<-sort_df(HSD.test(dataov,'fac'),'trt')
trtplt<-gl(3,10,30,labels=c("A","B","C"))
yrplt<-factor(substr(dathsd$trt,3,4))

prepanel.ci <- function(x, y, ly, uy, subscripts, ...) 
{ 
    x <- as.numeric(x) 
    ly <- as.numeric(ly[subscripts]) 
    uy <- as.numeric(uy[subscripts]) 
    list(ylim = range(y, uy, ly, finite = TRUE)) 
} 
panel.ci <- function(x, y, ly, uy, subscripts, pch = 16, ...) 
{ 
    x <- as.numeric(x) 
    y <- as.numeric(y) 
    ly <- as.numeric(ly[subscripts]) 
    uy <- as.numeric(uy[subscripts]) 
    panel.arrows(x, ly, x, uy, col = "black", 
                 length = 0.25, unit = "native", 
                 angle = 90, code = 3) 
    panel.xyplot(x, y, pch = pch, ...) 
} 

xyplot(dathsd$means~yrplt,group=trtplt,type=list("l","p"),
        ly=dathsd$means-dathsd$std.err,
        uy=dathsd$means+dathsd$std.err,
        prepanel = prepanel.ci, 
        panel = panel.superpose, 
        panel.groups = panel.ci 
        )
```

[image: This is the figure I would like mydata to be]!
[image: Using Deepayan's solution, I am able to add the error bar like this based on 2 factors]

Comment: @Marco I see you've also come up with a custom panel function whilst I was coming up with something similar. It would have been better to post your own answer rather than edit the Q as now the Q solves itself. If you post you solution as an answer, we can rollback the Q? Or have we still not answered the Q fully?

Comment: @Gavin, Sorry for the inconvenience, while posting the Q, I am also trying.

Comment: @Marco - no inconvenience, I think you've done a good job on the Q. Wasn't sure if what you posted was a solution or just extra code to get closer to a solution. I see from your comment below that we still aren't fully there. I've replied with a general solution.

Comment: I tried to be more closer to my goal, and the above figure only show the intermediate result. I think my goal is a 3-subplot figure that shows the three factors. I tried to use means ~ yrplt | factor3 and found only one line was shown in each subplot, representing only one treatment of factor1, maybe I need to adjust something in the main function of xyplot

Comment: I think the problem is more how should the data you show be split by the third factor. Perhaps you example data hasn't got enough replications to be split again by a third variable?

Comment: Sorry I should have included the third factor in the     aov   analysis

Comment: Depends, the multi-panel figure you include above appears to have different response variables on the y-axis. If that is like your real data, perhaps what you want is to run to N different `aov()` and `HSD.test()` and stack the outputs to produce the graph. If the response is the same, then you probably need to include this in the aov analysis somewhere.

Comment: @Gavin I have difference variables! Thanks, I think it is more easy to do it one by one! Thanks very much for the help~

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is another way of doing it, using the magic of `ggplot`.  Because ggplot will calculate summaries for you, I suspect it means you can skip the entire step of doing `aov`.

The key is that your data should be in single `data.frame` that you can pass to `ggplot`.  Note that I have created new sample data to demonstrate.

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
  value = runif(300),
  yr = rep(1:10, each=3),
  trt = rep(LETTERS[1:4], each=75),
  third = rep(c("T", "P", "Q"), each=100)
)

ggplot(df, aes(x=yr, y=value, colour=trt)) + 
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="line", size=2) +
  stat_summary(fun.ymin=min, fun.ymax=max, geom="errorbar") +
  facet_grid(~third)
```

[image]

You can go one step further and produce facets in two dimensions:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=yr, y=value, colour=trt)) + 
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="line", size=2) +
  stat_summary(fun.ymin=min, fun.ymax=max, geom="errorbar") +
  facet_grid(trt~third)
```

[image]

Comment: Wooo, this is pretty cool! Thanks very much, @Andrie! Only one question, I am wondering, why didn't the four factors A:D appear in each subplot?

Comment: @Marco I guess this would be the result of the factors not crossing at all.  If any of the factors crossed, they would have appeared in the same subplot.  In other words, it will be a result of the way the dummy data.frame is constructed.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem, I should have checked the example data. Thanks Andrie~

Comment: I had a problem when applying your ggplot code. There were everything except lines. I checked the data carefully but cannot find the reason.

Answer (score 2):

This gets pretty close, but I forget how to colour the error lines using the `group` variable in Lattice and Deepayan's book is at work.

```
## format a new data structure with all variables we want
dat <- data.frame(dathsd[, c(2,5)], treat = trtplt, yrplt = yrplt,
                  upr = dathsd$means + 2 * dathsd$std.err,
                  lwr = dathsd$means - 2 * dathsd$std.err)
## compute ylims
ylims <- range(dat$lwr, dat$upr)
ylims <- ylims + (c(-1,1) * (0.05 * diff(ylims)))
## plot
xyplot(means ~ yrplt, data = dat, group = treat, lwr = dat$lwr, upr = dat$upr,
       type = c("p","l"), ylim = ylims,
       panel = function(x, y, lwr, upr, ...) {
           panel.arrows(x0 = x, y0 = lwr, x1 = x, y1 = upr,
                        angle = 90, code = 3, length = 0.05)
           panel.xyplot(x, y, ...)
       })
```

And produces:

[image: xyplot with error bars]

Comment: @Gavin, thanks very much! Sorry that I changed the post just before your answer. I think I didnot express my though very clearly, I need to introduce a third factor (3 levels, for example), and then split the current figure into 3 subplots using this factor.

Comment: Well, that is easy. Which is the factor in the example data you want to split on? If this isn't in the data, can you fake something I can use? It is as easy as doing `means ~ yrplt | factor3` in the formula where `factor3` is the factor you want to split the data into 3 panels by.

Comment: @Gavin, thank very much! But how about the HSD.test, as I also tried to include the significance result from HSD.test into the figues.

Comment: @Marco How do you want to show/represent the significance? I usually see papers with bars or stars (*) over significant combinations. Also how are you defining significant? The output from `HSD.test()` doesn't seem to show significance so you need to create a variable that indicates significance or not.

Comment: By significance, I mean multicomparison result, ie, common letters show insignificant, or just a star to show overall difference. Why do you think the output from HSD.test() was not significance?

Comment: @Marco - I don't know what the output from `HSD.test()` is really. I see now that we can use the `M` column of `dathsd`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. For me, the problem is, if the third factor was introduced from the xyplot, the 'means' should be recalculated, which means that the third factor should be in the 'aov' and then in the 'HSD.test', and finally behind the '|'